# Get skype contact list and status in android

Tags: java, android, uri, skype

I am working on Skype integration with android.i am not getting any type of SDK or API that will make to get information easily.

I am using URI concept to call,video call or chat in Skype with android.
i find 1 link to get status of Skype user:

**http://mystatus.skype.com/skype_user_name**

but this url is not working properly.

******i want to get all contact list from Skype  programmatic **

**i want to display status of all contact person.******

Please help me. I have done lots of search. But I didn't get anything related this.

Comment: this python wrapper might be helpful: [Skype4py](https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py)

Comment: @MehulJoisar i don't know how to use this https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py in android..
please help me

Comment: After looking to issue list of that repo,I doubt that it won't work.Skype has shut down the api in december.and  skype doesn't provide any sdk to communicate using client apps.Sorry!

Comment: @MehulJoisar but this python may be workful code for me...
but i don't know how to convert that code into android

Comment: That is for desktop client.kindly go through it if you find any working APIs in that code then you can directly use it in android as webservice call.

Comment: @MehulJoisar how?...................................

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47385/discussion-between-mehul-joisar-and-dipali)

Comment: try this https://github.com/aditya-agarwal/Skype-Android# and https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=skype&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories

Comment: @dipali: have you found the answer for your question

Comment: I hope this link could be a work around for your question : http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/01/how-to-make-skype-audiovideo-call-and.html#close

Answer (score 6):

## **It will not work**

[Microsoft killed Skype third-party tools](http://www.infoworld.com/t/application-development/microsoft-kills-skype-third-party-tools-the-desktop-230101) for the desktop and there are no sdk's for Skype development.

**Like you alreaddy mentioned, the most you can do is use URIs to open the users skype client:**

> - Switching focus to the Skype    client. (See Start/switch focus to    the Skype client.)
> - Initiating audio calls to other Skype users, phones, or mobiles—both    one-to-one    dialogs and multi-party conferences.
>     (See Audio    call—implicit.)
> - Initiating video calls to another Skype user. (See Video call.)
> - Sending instant messages to an individual or establishing a group       multi-chat. (See Chats.)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745878(v=office.15).aspx